# Autenticación en Spring Boot contra usuarios del sistema gestor de bases de datos

Tags: spring-boot, spring, autenticación, spring-security

Tengo el siguiente problema, estoy desarrollando una aplicación web con spring boot, spring security y jdbc. Necesito que una vez el usuario de click en el boton de autenticarse en el formulario del login, mi aplicación compruebe que ese usuario es un usuario de mi gestor de base de datos, o sea, no necesito una tabla en mi base de datos con usuarios y contraseñas encriptadas, sino que compruebe contra el propio sistema gestor, en mi caso específico, pgAdmin4. En caso de que exista este usuario y  coincida con la contraseña, le de acceso a mi web. He buscado muchisimo información al respecto, pero no logro encontrar nada que me ayude, espero haber explicado bien que quiero hacer, y sobretodo encontrar ayuda aquí, gracias de antemano.

// Esta es mi clase de configuración de Spring Security

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> {
                            authorize
                                    .requestMatchers(
                                            "/css/**",
                                            "/js/**",
                                            "/vendor/**",
                                            "/scss/**",
                                            "/img/**"
                                    )
                                    .permitAll()
                                    .anyRequest().authenticated();
                        }
                ).formLogin(
                        form -> form
                                .loginPage("/login")
                                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
                                .permitAll()
                )
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler())
                .and()
                .logout(
                        logout -> logout
                                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                                .permitAll()
                )
        ;
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(
            AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Autowired
    void registerProvider(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler() {
        return new CustomAccessDeniedHandler();
    }
}
```

// Esta es mi clase de configuración del datasource

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {
    
    private Environment environment;

    @Autowired
    public DataSourceConfig(Environment environment){
        this.environment=environment;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource(){
        DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        String URL = "spring.datasource.jdbcUrl";
        driverManagerDataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty(URL));
        String DRIVER = "spring.datasource.driverClassName";
        driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(Objects.requireNonNull(environment.getProperty(DRIVER)));
        String USER = "spring.datasource.username";
        driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(Objects.requireNonNull(environment.getProperty(USER)));
        String PASS = "spring.datasource.password";
        driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(Objects.requireNonNull(environment.getProperty(PASS)));
        return driverManagerDataSource;
    }
}
```

// Esta es mi clase del proveedor de autenticación

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        String name = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        //Aquí quisiera configurar un datasource con el nombre de usuario y contraseña de arriba, y comprobar, si la conección se realizó correctamente, darle acceso a mi web al usuario, en caso contrario, pedirle que escriba un usuario y contraseña nueva.
        
        return null;
    }

    private boolean shouldAuthenticateAgainstThirdPartySystem() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Es importante no crear la conección con la base de datos antes, sino configurar y conectar a la base de datos en el método authenticate de la clase CustomAuthenticationProvider. Gracias

Comment: Te has explicado bien, pero nosotros tenemos que fiarnos de que has buscado y tratado de buscar una solución por tu cuenta. Si añades el código de lo que has intentado veremos que realmente has intentado algo y te podremos ayudar a partir de ese código. Aquí estamos para ayudar, no para hacer cosas de 0 según explicaciones dadas… No pretendo ser borde, solo darte un consejo para que la gente no sienta que quieres que te hagan los deberes de clase (por ejemplo) y estén dispuestos a ayudarte, además de que sea más fácil, ya que partimos de un código empezado y con cambiar dos cosas basta.

Comment: Michas gracias por el consejo, soy nuevo aquí, editaré mi pregunta.

Comment: Sin problema, animo.

Comment: Respondiendo a tu pregunta, desconozco `pgAdmin4`, pero quizá exista alguna forma de hacer una conexión con la DDBB mediante el usuario y contraseña especificados y analizando que devuelve el intento de conexión, proporcionar acceso o no.

Comment: Muchas gracias, precisamente eso quiero, pero no se como, he editado la pregunta, como me aconsejaron antes.

Answer (score 1):

respondo a mi propia pregunta por si alguien necesita algo parecido en algun momento.

Cree una clase RoutingDataSource, para agregar en tiempo de ejecución mi fuente de datos.

```
@Component
public class RoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    public static final int DEFAULT = 0;
    public static final int NEW = 1;

    private volatile int key = DEFAULT;

    public void setKey(int key){
        this.key = key;
    }

    private Map<Object,Object> dataSources = new HashMap<>();

    RoutingDataSource() {
        setTargetDataSources(dataSources);
    }

    public void addDataSource(int key, DataSource dataSource){
        dataSources.put(key,dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return key;
    }

    @Override
    @Nonnull
    public DataSource determineTargetDataSource() {
        return (DataSource) dataSources.get(key);
    }
}
```

Cree una clase de configuración para inicializar mi RoutingDataSource vacío, ya que al inicializar el proyecto, no tengo fuentes de datos.

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    public RoutingDataSource create() {
        return new RoutingDataSource();
    }
}
```

Por ultimo, el método authenticate lo modifiqué de la siguiente forma.

```
@Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        String URL = "spring.datasource.jdbcUrl";
        String DRIVER = "spring.datasource.driverClassName";
        String name = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        DataSource datasource = DataSourceBuilder
                .create()
                .url(environment.getProperty(URL))
                .driverClassName(environment.getProperty(DRIVER))
                .username(name)
                .password(password)
                .build();
        try {
            Connection connection = datasource.getConnection();

            routingDataSource.addDataSource(RoutingDataSource.NEW, datasource);
            routingDataSource.setKey(RoutingDataSource.NEW);

            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    name, password, new ArrayList<>());

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

No se si es la forma correcta de hacer esto, pero simplemente me funcionó bien, gracias por la ayuda.